How can I install RedisGears in a Kubernetes Redis cluster created using the Bitnami redis-cluster Helm chart?
I have a live Redis cluster in AKS that was created using the Bitnami redis-cluster Helm chart. How can I install RedisGears into this existing cluster?

modified the Redis configuration to enable the MODULE command, but faced challenges with setting this option correctly in a live environment.

attempted to use kubectl cp to transfer the redisgears.so file to the Redis containers, but encountered errors due to a read-only file system and other permission issues.

considered updating the Redis image to a custom one that includes RedisGears but faced difficulties with this approach.


I would Like to Know what is correct approach to have redis gears in cluster
